# Force YouTube to play video in 360p

Tags: youtube

I have a high speed internet connection at home, so YouTube buffers every video in 720p by default. The problem is, once the consumption reaches 5 GB, internet speed is cut down to 512 kbps. So I want to set YouTube to buffer all videos at 360p by default. Upon a little fiddling around with YouTube settings, I found a setting in which allows you to tell YouTube that "never play higher quality videos" in Settings -> Playback. But it doesn't seem to work.

[image: screen shot].

I saw some posts on the Google Product Forums which say that when YouTube detects high speed it will automatically switch to HD video playback. But then what's the point of giving the above option to the user?

I have to manually change the quality every single time I play a video. How do I force YouTube to stream videos in 360p by default?

I am using Chrome browser on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the Chrome extension [ImprovedTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improvedtube-youtube-exte/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd?hl=en). One of the features it has is to set the default video quality.

Comment: Saved me GBs of bandwidth, thanks! :)